# When write code to BSC this error occurs

Tags: bsc

Solidity 0.8.4 \ Single File

```
Compiler debug log:
 Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (Expected library(ies) but one or more was not provided)
 Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : Context, DividendPayingToken, ERC20, MYCOIN, HLDividendTracker, IDividendPayingToken, IDividendPayingTokenOptional, IERC20, IUniswapV2Factory, IUniswapV2Pair, IUniswapV2Router01, IUniswapV2Router02, IterableMapping, Ownable, SafeMath, SafeMathInt, SafeMathUint
 But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)
 For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions
```

Comment: What's the deployed address? What's the transaction that deployed the contract? What's the contract code? What are the compilation parameters? solc version, number of runs, are optimization enabled. What were the constructor parameters?

Comment: The code is the same, I haven't changed anything

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you since you haven't provided any data. In all the cases the problem usually is that some of the parameters is not correct: wrong solc version, wrong constructor's parameters, wrong compilation settings, wrong source code, etc.